# Installing mechanize gem on Mac OS X 10.4.11 gives 'Failed to build gem native extension'

Tags: macos, rubygems, mechanize-ruby

I'm trying to install mechanize gem on a MAC OS X but I keep getting the following error :

> ERROR:  Error installing mechanize:
>           ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb install mechanize
>   checking for #include 
>   ... yes
>   checking for #include 
>   ... yes
>   checking for #include 
>   ... yes
>   checking for #include 
>   ... yes
>   checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... yes
>   checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc() in -lxslt... yes
>   checking for exsltFuncRegister() in -lexslt... yes
>   creating Makefile
>
> ** make
>   gcc -I. -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-darwin8.9.1 -I. -I/opt/local/include/ -I/opt/local/include/libxml2  -fno-common -g -O2 -pipe -fno-common  -g -DXP_UNIX -O3 -Wall -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Wmissing-noreturn -Winline  -c html_document.c
>   In file included from ./html_document.h:4,
>                    from html_document.c:1:
>   ./native.h:11:28: error: libxml/xmlsave.h: No such file or directory
>   make: * ** [html_document.o] Error 1**

So xmlsave.h could not be found inside /opt/local/include/ or /opt/local/include/libxml2
The thing is libxml2 is installed as a framework at /Library/Frameworks/libxml2.framework/

Then I decided to create a symlink from libxml headers directory to /opt/local/include/xml2 so I did

```
ln -s /Library/Frameworks/libxml2.framework/Headers/libxml/ libxml2
```

but I still can't install the gem.

Any pointers or ideas are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue, not installing mechanize but webrat.  Here's what worked for me:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/include/libxml2 /opt/local/include/libxml2
```